# At creation time, why are shortcut titles translated, but menu link titles are not?

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

The idiom that the community points to for [creating menu links](https://api.drupal.org/comment/60056#comment-60056) usually looks like this (from `\Drupal\Tests\language\Functional\LanguageSwitchingTest::testLanguageSessionSwitchLinks()`):

```php
// Add a link to the homepage.
$link = MenuLinkContent::create([
  'title' => 'Home',
  'menu_name' => 'main',
  'bundle' => 'menu_link_content',
  'link' => [['uri' => 'entity:user/2']],
]);
$link->save();
```

Note that the `title` is not run through `t()`.

But, yet, the idiom for shortcut links (from `standard_install()`) is:

```php
// Populate the default shortcut set.
$shortcut = Shortcut::create([
  'shortcut_set' => 'default',
  'title' => t('Add content'),
  'weight' => -20,
  'link' => ['uri' => 'internal:/node/add'],
]);
$shortcut->save();
```

Note that the `title` *is* run through `t()`.

Why are shortcut titles run through translation at creation time, but menu link titles are not? Aren't shortcuts a type of menu link? Shouldn't they be handled the same way?

Comment: You may have found a bug there - shortcuts are content entities and title is a field, so it probably shouldn't go through `t`

Comment: Just checked, almost definitely a bug - shortcuts don't render using the interface translation on a vanilla install so using `t` on the title in `standard_install` is pointless at best